# How to automatically select or deselect the all child nodes whenever its parent Node is selected or deselected?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one Tree View Control with check boxes in my Windows Forms Application.How to automatically select or deselect the all child nodes whenever its parent Node is selected or deselected?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the sample code in the documentation for the [AfterCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx) event does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Sourav, you mean, because I did not duplicate the code from the documentation? It is available in the link I provided. That said, you're right, I probably should not have answered this question, but voted to close it because of a lack of research effort. I was still learning the ropes back in 2011...

Answer (score 15):

```
    private void HandleOnTreeViewAfterCheck(Object sender,
       TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckTreeViewNode(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
    }

    private void CheckTreeViewNode(TreeNode node, Boolean isChecked)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode item in node.Nodes)
        {
            item.Checked = isChecked;

            if (item.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                this.CheckTreeViewNode(item, isChecked);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the foreach loop traversing the tree recursively? ie is e.Node.Nodes walking the branch?

Comment: No. Just one level. Assumed his req was with just one level. I added code to do recursive check. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @VijaySirigiri This logic is a little risky because when you check the child item inside the foreach, you make his AfterCheck event firing too, so the cascading effect becomes unpredictable

Comment: My advice to improve the code above would be to perform this check before calling CheckTreeViewNode method:  
`if(e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)`

Answer (score 1):

```
            //TreeView - myTreeview;
            myTreeview.BeginUpdate();
            //Loop through all the nodes of tree
            foreach (TreeNode node in myTreeview.Nodes)
            {
                //If node has child nodes
                if (HasChildNodes(node))
                {
                    if (node.Checked == true)
                    {
                        //Check all the child nodes.
                        foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
                        {
                            childNode.Checked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            myTreeview.EndUpdate();

Hope this helps....
```

Comment: You can make a method and call it from treeviewbeforecheck event so it will check all the tree nodes

Comment: Above post helps u or u stuck somewhere

Comment: @Tech Giant: How to create treeviewbeforecheck event?

Answer (score 1):

Use **AfterCheck** event of the treeview to code for what should happen to the child nodes inside the treeview.

pass the same state of the tree view node to its child also and set its "**checked**" property to the same state of the treeview node.

Comment: how to create AfterCheck event in c#.net?

Comment: just right click the treeview in the form , go to properties. In that select event tab. Here you will find the list of events associated with this control. Double click on the "AfterCheck" event and it gets generated for you.

Answer (score 1):

Pleas find the working code below. I am using this in my application. Hope this will solve the issue.

```
private void tree_Documents_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode checkedNode = e.Node;
        foreach (TreeNode node in checkedNode.Nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = checkedNode.Checked;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't check/uncheck the grandchildren of the `checkedNode`.

Answer (score 1):

This simple code works for me

```
private void treeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
        try {
            e.Node.TreeView.BeginUpdate();
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0) {
                var parentNode = e.Node;
                var nodes = e.Node.Nodes;
                CheckedOrUnCheckedNodes(parentNode, nodes);
            }
        } finally {
            e.Node.TreeView.EndUpdate();
        }
    }

private void CheckedOrUnCheckedNodes(TreeNode parentNode, TreeNodeCollection nodes) {
        if (nodes.Count > 0) {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes) {
                node.Checked = parentNode.Checked;
                CheckedOrUnCheckedNodes(parentNode, node.Nodes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
        {
            node.Checked = nodeChecked;
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
            }
        }
    }
    private void treeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
        {
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                if (!e.Node.Checked)
                {
                    this.CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
                }
            }
        }

        if (e.Node.Parent != null)
        {
            TreeNode n = e.Node;
            while (n.Parent != null)
            {
                if (n.Checked)
                {
                    n.Parent.Checked = true;
                }
                n = n.Parent;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add some comments to your code and explain it!

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not TreeView1.Nodes(e.Node.Text) Is Nothing Then
    For Each node As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes(e.Node.Text).Nodes
            If node.Parent.Checked = True Then
                node.Checked = True
            End If
            If node.Parent.Checked = False Then
                node.Checked = False
            End If

        Next
    End If
```

Comment: The OP specifies the language as C#, so please do not post code in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this for check and uncheck parent node as well on click on child node.

```
    private void CheckTreeViewNode(TreeNode node, Boolean isChecked)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode item in node.Nodes)
        {
            item.Checked = isChecked;

            if (item.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                this.CheckTreeViewNode(item, isChecked);
            }
        }

        if (isChecked && node.Parent != null)
        {
            treeView1.AfterCheck -= HandleOnTreeViewAfterCheck;
            node.Parent.Checked = true;
            treeView1.AfterCheck += HandleOnTreeViewAfterCheck;
        }


        if (!isChecked && node.Parent != null)
        {
            bool unchk = true;
            treeView1.AfterCheck -= HandleOnTreeViewAfterCheck;
            foreach (TreeNode item in node.Parent.Nodes)
            {
                if (item.Checked)
                {
                    unchk = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (unchk)
                node.Parent.Checked = false;

            treeView1.AfterCheck += HandleOnTreeViewAfterCheck;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Nodes.Count != 0)
    {
        if (e.Node.Checked)
        {
            CheckAllChildNodes1(e.Node);
        }
        else
        {
            UncheckChildNodes1(e.Node);
        }
    }
}

private void CheckAllChildNodes1(TreeNode treeNodeAdv)
{
    foreach (TreeNode nd in treeNodeAdv.Nodes)
    {
        nd.Checked = treeNodeAdv.Checked;
    }
}

private void UncheckChildNodes1(TreeNode treeNodeAdv)
{
    foreach (TreeNode nd in treeNodeAdv.Nodes)
    {
        nd.Checked = treeNodeAdv.Checked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my solution:

Check all subnodes of node:

```
internal static void CheckAllSubNodesRecursive(
    TreeNode treeNode,
    bool checkNode)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        if (!node.Checked && checkNode)
        {
            node.Checked = true;
        }
        if (node.Checked && !checkNode)
        {
            node.Checked = false;
        }

        if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            CheckAllSubNodesRecursive(node, checkNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Handle parent node checking:

```
internal static void ValidateParentNodeCheckRecursive(
    TreeNode treeNode)
{
    if (treeNode.Parent == null ||
        treeNode.Parent.GetType() != typeof(TreeNode))
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (TreeNode subNode in treeNode.Parent.Nodes)
    {
        if (subNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            ValidateParentNodeCheckRecursive(subNode);
        }

        subNode.Parent.Checked = subNode.Parent.Nodes
            .Cast<TreeNode>()
            .ToList()
            .All(c => c.Checked);
    }
}
```

These functions can be added to a static class, e.g, `ViewExtensions`.
Remember to disable/enable treeView_AfterCheck events.